# What if the random variable are not IID, and we sum them?

Tags: normal-distribution, kolmogorov-complexity

Let $a_n > 0$ be decreasing with $\sum a_n^2=1$. Starting at the origin we do drunken random walk on the real line, with step size $a_1,a_2...$, so the total deviation is $\sum a_n^2=1$. If our position is $s_n$ at step $n$, is $s_n$ approaching to the normal distribution? That would be expected, and cool.

Comment: CLT is a phenomenon where small and almost uncorrelated quantities sum up together to build up a fluctuation. In particular, term-wise contribution is smudged out. Here, the situation is quite the other extreme. Terms that are far apart live on different scales, and contribution from each single term is frozen and survives to the infinity. There is no reason to expect that the limiting distribution is Gaussian, as explained by example in the answer below.

Comment: Actually, what I had in mind was the special case $a_n={1\over \sqrt{P+n}}$ and we make exactly $P$ steps to get $s_P$. Is the distribution of $s_p$ converging to the normal distribution if $P\to \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Intuition comes from the limiting case $a_1=1, a_2=a_3=...=0$, in which case the process only takes one step and its distribution does not converge to a Gaussian.  A positive counter-example comes whenever $a_1=1-\epsilon$ for suitably small $\epsilon>0$ (shown below).

---

Fix $a_1 \in (1/2,1)$.  Let $\{a_n\}_{n=2}^{\infty}$ be any positive numbers that satisfy $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_n^2 = 1-a_1^2$. Let $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be iid with $P[X_i=-1]=P[X_i=1]=1/2$ and define $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i X_i$. The variance of $S_n$ indeed converges to $1$.

However, for $n \in \{2, 3, 4, ...\}$:
$$ \left\{S_n \in [-1/4 , 1/4] \right\} \subseteq \left\{\left|\sum_{i=2}^n a_iX_i\right|\geq 1/4\right\}$$
Thus: 
\begin{align}
P[S_n \in [-1/4, 1/4]] &\leq P\left[\left|\sum_{i=2}^n a_iX_i\right|> 1/4\right]\\
&\leq \frac{E\left[(\sum_{i=2}^n a_iX_i)^2\right]}{(1/4)^2}\\
&= 16\sum_{i=2}^n a_i^2 \\
&\leq 16(1-a_1^2)
\end{align}
This can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $a_1$ very close to 1. So then when $a_1$ is sufficiently close to $1$,   $P\left[S_n \in [-1/4,1/4]\right]$ cannot converge to $\int_{-1/4}^{1/4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2}dx$.

---

A deterministic example is when $a_i = \frac{2^{-i}}{2}$ for $i \in \{2, 3, 4, ...\}$ and $a_1^2 = 1-\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} a_i^2$.   Then $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} a_i = 1/4$, $\sum_{i=2}^{\infty} a_i^2 < 1/4$, and $a_1>\sqrt{3/4}>1/2$.  So then the process moves a distance larger than 1/2 on the first jump, but a sum total distance at most 1/4 on all other jumps.  So $P[S_n \in [-1/4, 1/4]]=0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Actually, what I had in mind was the special case $a_n={1\over }

Comment: Actually, what I had in mind was the special case a) $a_n={1\over \sqrt{P+n}}$ and we make exactly $P$ steps to get $s_p$, b) $a_n={1\over {P+n}}$ and we make infinite number of steps to get $S_p$. Are the distribution of $s_p$ and $S_p$ converging to the normal distribution if $\P\to \infty$?

Comment: Actually, what I had in mind was the special case $a_n={1\over \sqrt{P+n}}$ and we make exactly $P$ steps to get $s_P$. Is the distribution of $s_p$  converging to the normal distribution if $P\to \infty$?

Comment: This looks like you are switching to a new question.  It may be better to accept my existing answer.  For your new one, if $a_n=1/(P+n)$ then  $\lim_{P\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{P+n} \right)^2 = 0$ so the variance goes to 0; if $a_n = 1/\sqrt{P+n}$ and we take $P$ steps, this looks like it goes to a Gaussian with variance $\log(2)$, by a quick MGF approximation $$E[e^{t S_P}] \approx \prod_{n=1}^P (1 + \frac{t^2}{2(P+n)}) \rightarrow e^{\log(2)t^2/2}$$